# How can we justify that we can generate random point on a compact set with all point being equally likely ?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, compactness, random

In [this article](https://maa.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/0025570X.2017.1419769?needAccess=true), at page 120, the author states that

> the question was solved for three random points forming a spherical 
>   triangle on the n-dimensional sphere.[...]since the sphere is compact,
>   then points can be generated randomly on the sphere with all points being equally likely.

However, is there any justification for why we can generate random point on a compact set (in this case a subset of Euclidean space) with all point being equally likely ? (whereas if this is not the case, we cannot)

Comment: Is this the axiom of choice?  If so, perhaps the author is accepting that axiom.

Comment: It's very unclear what "all points being equally likely" means for an uncountable set. What the author means is that you can generate random points on a sphere in such a way that the probability that a point lies in a given region is proportional to that region's area; this is what "uniform probability measure on a sphere" ought to mean.

Comment: What Qiaochu Yuan said. I just wonder what the relation between compactness and existence of a nice measure is in general? I'm sure we can cook up compact topological spaces, where it is difficult to see what a nice uniform measure would look like. Anyway, on an $n$-dimensional sphere we have a natural measure that is uniform in the sense that we have a transitive group of homeomorphisms keeping the measure invariant. That's probably what is implied/intended here.

Comment: And there are algorithms for generating such points. Though the obvious one quickly becomes less efficient when $n>3$ grows.